Dependent date selections
I have a Google spreadsheet that contains a list of events displayed in a 5-week calendar format.
These are 2-day events however the first and second day are roughly two weeks apart.
A user selects their preferred first and second dates within the following framework:

The first date must be within weeks 1-3.
The second date must be within the week number that is two weeks after the first date. For example, in f:s, where f is the week containing the first date, and s is the week in which the second week must be selected:

Week 1:Week 3
Week 2:Week 4
Week 3:Week 5



Is there a way in Google Sheets to limit the choice of the second week based on the first week selected?

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Google Sheets is a very flexible tool. Please provide more details about the spreadsheet structure, how the selections will be done and how the validation will be done.

This question is not related to [tag:conditional-formatting], please don't add this tag again.

You haven't provided much detail about the layout of your spreadsheet or the events however the basic concept around dependent dropdowns remains the same.
My example is based on the two parameters you provided:

You have two groups of events, Events1 and Events2, and from each one a single event must be selected:

Events1 all fall within the same 3-week period.
Events2 all fall within the same 3-week period.
The 3 weeks for Events2 starts 2 weeks after the start of the 3-week period for Events1. For example,if events1= weeks 1,2,3, then events2= weeks 3,4,5



An event, Choice1, will be selected from Events1, and another, Choice2, from Events2.

Choice1 must be before Choice2
Choice2 must be in a week that is 2 weeks later than the week of Choice1.  For example,if Choice1 = week 2, then Choice2 = week 4



For simplicity, all the example data is in the same sheet however in practice the dropdowns would be on a different sheet.

Formula in C2
=LET(Choice1,A2, Choice2,A5,
   Events1,F2:F, Events2,G2:G,
   First,INDEX(Events1,1),
   Weeks,INDEX(First-WEEKDAY(First)+1+SEQUENCE(5,1,0,7)), 
   Ch1wk,VLOOKUP(Choice1,Weeks,1,1),
   Ch2wk,VLOOKUP(Choice1+14,Weeks,1,1),
   IFNA(HSTACK(IF(Choice2<>"",
     FILTER(Events1, Events1>=Ch1wk, Events1<Ch1wk+7), Events1),
     FILTER(Events2, Events2>=Ch2wk, Events2<Ch2wk+7))))

HSTACK  IFNA  INDEX  LET  SEQUENCE  VLOOKUP
Link to sample spreadsheet
Note that anyone with the link can edit the document anonymously so you may wish to save a copy to your own drive.
Explanation

LET stores values and calculations for reuse.
Choice1 and Choice2 store the current values from the dropdowns in A2 and A5.  The dropdowns are created using data validation rules:

Navigate to data validation rules: Menu: Data > Data validation > Add rule or Keyboard:
Alt+Shift+D V > Add rule.
Choice1 rule in A2:  Range:     A2
Criteria:  Dropdown (from a range)
           =F2:F

Choice2 rule in A5:  Range:     A5
Criteria:  Dropdown (from a range)
           =G2:G



Events1 F2:F, is a 3-week sequence of dates starting from 4/28/2024.
Events2 G2:G, is a 3-week sequence of dates starting from 5/12/2024 (2 weeks after 4/28/2024).
First is the first event in Events1 returned by INDEX
Weeks stores an array containing the first day of each of 5 weeks, starting with the week containing First.  It is used as a lookup table to determine what week a selected date is in. The array is calculated by:

First determine the first day of the week, of the week containing the first event. This is done using WEEKDAY which will return the day of the week for any date.  By subtracting the result from First and then adding 1, the date becomes the first day of the week:
="4/30/2024" - WEEKDAY("4/30/2024") + 1         
="4/30/2024" - 3 + 1                     // 3 = Tuesday
="4/28/2024"          

=WEEKDAY("4/28/2024")     
=1                                       //  1 = Sunday 


The resulting date from the previous step is then added to a sequence of 5 numbers starting with 0 and incrementing by 7 {0; 7; 14; 21; 28} which results in an array of five 5 dates corresponding to the first day of each of the 5 weeks.


Ch1wk returns the actual week associated with Choice1 using VLOOKUP and the Weeks array just created.
Ch2wk returns the valid week for Choice2 by performing the same lookup but first adding 2 weeks/14 days to Choice2
Now armed with the valid weeks for Choice1 and Choice2 the List_Choice1 and List_Choice2 can be returned in Columns C and D:

The dropdowns are using these results to populate themselves
The results will change as the selections change and the dropdown options will dynamically update to reflect them.


The first column is List_Choice1 which is populated using an IF and a FILTER:
IF(Choice2<>"",
   FILTER(Events1, Events1>=Ch1wk, Events1<Ch1wk+7),
   Events1)


If Choice2 is not populated, then all events from Events1 are returned.
If Choice2 is populated (which can only happen if Choice1 was already populated), then the results are limited to other events in the same week as Ch1wk the week of the current Choice1. This ensures that after a selection is made the logic is maintained. Note that clearing Choice2 will re-enable the ability to select any event from Events1.


List_Choice2 is populated using a FILTER of Events2 to return only those events whose dates are within  Ch2wk.
FILTER(Events2, Events2>=ch2wk, Events2<ch2wk+7)

The FILTER will only return values if Ch2wk is populated with a valid date, which will not happen if Choice1 is not yet populated, in that case, List_Choice2 will remain empty.

Example Images
Click to enlarge

Choice1=  , Choice2= 

Choice1=5/6/2024, Choice2= 

Choice1=5/6/2024, Choice2=5/22/2024

Closed Dropdown View

Open Dropdown View**




Markdown Table




A
B    
C
D
E    
F
G




1
Choice1

List_Choice1
List_Choice2

Events1
Events2


2


Sun 04/28/2024


Sun 04/28/2024
Sun 05/12/2024


3


Mon 04/29/2024


Mon 04/29/2024
Mon 05/13/2024


4
Choice2

Tue 04/30/2024


Tue 04/30/2024
Tue 05/14/2024


5


Wed 05/01/2024


Wed 05/01/2024
Wed 05/15/2024


6


Thu 05/02/2024


Thu 05/02/2024
Thu 05/16/2024


7


Fri 05/03/2024


Fri 05/03/2024
Fri 05/17/2024


8


Sat 05/04/2024


Sat 05/04/2024
Sat 05/18/2024


9


Sun 05/05/2024


Sun 05/05/2024
Sun 05/19/2024


10


Mon 05/06/2024


Mon 05/06/2024
Mon 05/20/2024


11


Tue 05/07/2024


Tue 05/07/2024
Tue 05/21/2024


12


Wed 05/08/2024


Wed 05/08/2024
Wed 05/22/2024


13


Thu 05/09/2024


Thu 05/09/2024
Thu 05/23/2024


14


Fri 05/10/2024


Fri 05/10/2024
Fri 05/24/2024


15


Sat 05/11/2024


Sat 05/11/2024
Sat 05/25/2024


16


Sun 05/12/2024


Sun 05/12/2024
Sun 05/26/2024


17


Mon 05/13/2024


Mon 05/13/2024
Mon 05/27/2024


18


Tue 05/14/2024


Tue 05/14/2024
Tue 05/28/2024


19


Wed 05/15/2024


Wed 05/15/2024
Wed 05/29/2024


20


Thu 05/16/2024


Thu 05/16/2024
Thu 05/30/2024


21


Fri 05/17/2024


Fri 05/17/2024
Fri 05/31/2024


22


Sat 05/18/2024


Sat 05/18/2024
Sat 06/01/2024



